# Unit testing service doesn't inject Factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm new to **unit testing** with `jasmine`, and I've got some issues while trying to make it work. I'm using a project generated with `yeoman`, using `gulp-angular` generator.

I have a service :

```
export class AuthService {
   constructor (FactoryAppStateService) {
    'ngInject';

    this.FactoryAppStateService = FactoryAppStateService;
    this.test = 'toto';
  }

  login (loginInfos) {
    var user = {
        'userName' : loginInfos.username,
        'token' : 'token'
    }
    var credentials = {
      'cientId' : 'testFromService',
      'clientSecret' : 'testFromService'
    }
    this.FactoryAppStateService.setUser(user);
    this.FactoryAppStateService.setClientId(credentials.clientId);
    this.FactoryAppStateService.setClientSecret(credentials.clientSecret);
    this.test = 'tata';
    return user.token;
  }

  getTest () {
    return this.test;
  }
}
```

and a test :

```
describe('service Auth', () => {
  // load the service's module
  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('monNotaireFront'));

  it('should do something', function () {
    var service;

    angular.mock.inject(function GetDependencies(AuthService) {
      service = AuthService;
    });

    expect(service.getTest()).toBe('tata');
  });
});
```

And I'm getting this Error :

> PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0) service Auth should do something
>   FAILED
>           Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: FactoryAppStateServiceProvider <- FactoryAppStateService <-
>   AuthService
>           http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/unpr?p0=FactoryAppStateServiceProvider%20%3C-%20FactoryAppStateService%20%3C-%20AuthService
>               at C:/Users/gayard/Documents/Dev/monnotaire-angularjs/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4289
>               at getService (C:/Users/gayard/Documents/Dev/monnotaire-angularjs/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4437)
>               at C:/Users/gayard/Documents/Dev/monnotaire-angularjs/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4294
>               at getService (C:/Users/gayard/Documents/Dev/monnotaire-angularjs/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4437)
>               at invoke (C:/Users/gayard/Documents/Dev/monnotaire-angularjs/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4469)
>               at instantiate (C:/Users/gayard/Documents/Dev/monnotaire-angularjs/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4486)
>               at C:/Users/gayard/Documents/Dev/monnotaire-angularjs/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4346
>               at invoke (C:/Users/gayard/Documents/Dev/monnotaire-angularjs/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4478)
>               at enforcedReturnValue (C:/Users/gayard/Documents/Dev/monnotaire-angularjs/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4330)
>               at invoke (C:/Users/gayard/Documents/Dev/monnotaire-angularjs/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4478)
>               at C:/Users/gayard/Documents/Dev/monnotaire-angularjs/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4295
>               at getService (C:/Users/gayard/Documents/Dev/monnotaire-angularjs/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4437)
>               at invoke (C:/Users/gayard/Documents/Dev/monnotaire-angularjs/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4469)
>               at workFn (C:/Users/gayard/Documents/Dev/monnotaire-angularjs/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2438)
>               at C:/Users/gayard/Documents/Dev/monnotaire-angularjs/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2410
>               at C:/Users/gayard/Documents/Dev/monnotaire-angularjs/.tmp/serve/app/index.module.js:9

And I have no idea why the factory used by my service can't be injected.
I was trying different solutions like this one before :

```
describe('service Auth', () => {
  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('monNotaireFront'));

  let AuthService;

  beforeEach(inject((_AuthService_) => {
    AuthService = _AuthService_;
  }));

  it("should return tata", () => {
    AuthService.login({username : 'test'});
    expect(AuthService.getTest()).toEqual('tata');
  });

});
```

But same error occurred .
 **Please explain what could be the reason?**

Comment: Does this code also fails on the browser? or only on the test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved ! It was a bad declaration of FactoryAppStateService. To be simple, instead of

```
angular.module([]).factory('FactoryAppState', (localStorageService) => {return new FactoryAppState(localStorageService)})
```

i was doing

```
angular.module([]).factory('FactoryAppState', FactoryAppState)
```